# PHP preg_replace add brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have string like this:

```
xxx - 12, ABC DEF GHI
```

I want to replace this string like this

```
xxx - 12, (ABC DEF GHI)
```

Moreover the string which I added into bracket is dynamic.

The format is:

```
STRING - NUMBER, STRING
```

Brackets starts after `NUMBER,` string found and ends at the end of string.
So replace pattern is

```
STRING - NUMBER, (STRING)
```

Comment: In which way it is dynamic? What is the logic to decide where to place the brackets? The last 11 characters, or the part that starts with A until the end, or the last three words, or what follows the first comma (trimmed), or consecutive capital letters with optional internal spaces, or ....?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your pattern and replacement like this :

```
$str = "xxx - 12, ABC DEF GHI";
$pattern = "/([A-Z]+ - [0-9]+,) ([A-Z\s]+)/i";
$replace = "$1 ($2)";
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$str);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/025DN)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\d,\h*\K.*\S~', '($0)', $str);
```

pattern details:

```
~         # pattern delimiter
\d,       # a digit followed by a comma
\h*       # zero or more horizontal whitespaces
\K        # start the match result at this position
.* \S     # zero or more characters until the last non-whitespace character
~
```

In the replacement string `$0` refers to the whole match, but since I used `\K` in the pattern, the whole match is only the part matched by `.*\S`.

Feel free to describe what happens before the digit and the comma if needed.